# Text involving special symbols in python and command prompt

Tags: python, windows, cmd, character-encoding

I'm going to print something involving special phonetic symbols with python 3.4. In IDLE and cmd I tried, it raised UnicodeEncodeError or something similar. After those failures, I create a txt saved in 'utf-8' to test it out. In the txt, it is `abæʃ`. And I write:

```
import sys
sys.stdout._encoding='cp65001'
f=open('test.txt')
c=f.read()
print(c)
print(c.encode())
```

In IDLE, it returns:

```
>>> 
ï»¿abÃ¦Êƒ
b'\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbb\xc2\xbfab\xc3\x83\xc2\xa6\xc3\x8a\xc6\x92'
```

When tested in cmd, it return the first row different with that from IDLE, but still in mess, but when I used '>>'(redirection) in cmd, from the file I saw they were the same.

I don't know why there's something before ab, and why can't either IDLE or cmd return the correct string even the encoding are the same. Why did it happen, and how can I solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: CPython 3.4 encodes/decodes interactive standard I/O using the console codepage that's active when the `sys.std*` files are created at startup, and otherwise uses `locale.getpreferredencoding()` (i.e. the ANSI codepage on Windows). You can force an encoding via the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable. You can set the console codepage via the `chcp.com` command, but 65001 (UTF-8) is buggy and will probably never be fixed because Windows doesn't support UTF-8 as the ANSI/OEM codepage. Instead use the wide-character API via [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

Comment: To expand on the default being `getpreferredencoding()`, that also applies to built-in `open`. If the file is UTF-8  you have to explicitly open it as such, e.g. `f = open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8')`. The Python community has a significant bias toward Unix systems, which primarily use UTF-8 as the locale encoding, so a lot of Python 3 programmers aren't even aware of the actual defaults used by `io.TextIOWrapper`. They just assume it's UTF-8, especially since that's the default encoding for Python 3 source files.